# Picasso disk cache not working

Tags: android, caching, dependency-injection, picasso

I use picasso to download and cache image but the images does't cache but download successfully  and i don't fin the problem and i use dagger to decency inject picasso object also but i don't think that is the problem

Here is my code at the adapter as i pass picasso to the adapter object

```
    picasso.load(currentClient.getLogoUrl())
            .placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .into(holder.clientImage);
```

And my di code

```
@Module(includes = {ContextModule.class, NetworkModule.class})
public class PicassoModule {

    @Provides
    @InmaaApplicationScope
    public Picasso picasso(@ApplicationContext Context context, OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader) {
        return new Picasso.Builder(context)
                .downloader(okHttp3Downloader)
                .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @InmaaApplicationScope
    public OkHttp3Downloader okHttp3Downloader(OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        return new OkHttp3Downloader(okHttpClient);
    }
}
```

The other module

```
@Module(includes = ContextModule.class)
public class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @InmaaApplicationScope
    public HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor(message -> Timber.i(message));
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BASIC);
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Provides
    @InmaaApplicationScope
    public Cache cache(File cacheFile) {
        return new Cache(cacheFile, 512 * 1024 * 1024); //512 MB for cache
    }

    @Provides
    @InmaaApplicationScope
    public File cacheFile(@ApplicationContext Context context) {
        return new File(context.getCacheDir(), "okhttp_cache");
    }

    @Provides
    @InmaaApplicationScope
    public OkHttpClient okHttpClient(HttpLoggingInterceptor loggingInterceptor, Cache cache) {
        return new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
    }

}
```

at the Activity code

```
  @Inject
    Picasso picasso;

        clientsAdapter = new ClientsAdapter(picasso);
```

The state of the cache folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I think you forgot to actually set the Picasso instance:</strike>

```
Picasso.setSingletonInstance(/* insert your instance here*/));
```

This has to be done before you load any image with Picasso.

Since you are using your own Picasso instance I guess the images don't have proper caching headers. See the comments below.

Comment: i don't use picasso Singleton i use di so i pass it as parameter to the adapter i will but the activity code for more explanation

Comment: Picasso uses 2 caching mechanisms: Memory Cache managed by Picasso itself and a Disk Cache managed by the Http-Client. I guess you want to use the second one. The (Ok)Http Client caching depends on the caching header sent by the image server. Maybe those are invalid?

Comment: the image come from the firebase storage

Comment: You can add an Loggin-Interceptor to your OkHttpClient instance to see which caching headers are active. Here is a link to the documentation how to set them: https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers

Comment: i already adding the Interceptor  but how to know the active cache header]

Comment: The important Header are the response header (not request). Some of them look like these: `Cache-Control: private, max-age=300` or `Etag: bd3cd970b981b633f919868573933d9d046b9a9c`. But others are possible aswell. If they are missing you have to add them somehow or OkHttp won't cache your images.

Comment: i don't see them in the log so how can i add them

Comment: I'm not sure. They have to be set within the Firebase storage.

Comment: I think i can't add them i think i will use picasso own cache

Comment: I think the image maybe cached check the image in the question

Comment: The image might be added to the cache but not used because the caching headers are outdated! You can check this by adding an Interceptor which forces the cache usage. More informations can be found here: https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Recipes